# Binary patching using radare2 in debug mode

Tags: radare2, patching

Im a newbe in radare and while I tried to patch a crackme binary, I opened it the first time in debug mode (-d), while debugging I used oo+ to reopen it with write mode, when I modify an instruction using wx, it works but when I quit it gives me two confirmation messages with yes no I press enter two times, then it get back to the original stat, and loose the modification, 
How could I keep changes even after quitting ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried opening a binary file and patching and it actually saves my patches. The steps I followed are:

```
[99:99:99] <myuser>:answer $ cp crackme0x00 crackme0x00_patched
[99:99:99] <myuser>:answer $ radare2 -Aw crackme0x00_patched
[0x08048360]> pdf@sym.main 
[0x08048360]> 0x08048487
[0x08048487]> wa ret
Written 1 bytes (ret) = wx c3
[0x08048487]> q
[99:99:99] <myuser>:answer $ cmp -l crackme0x00 crackme0x00_patched | gawk '{printf "%08X %02X %02X\n", $1, strtonum(0$2), strtonum(0$3)}' 
00000488 E8 C3
```

(I stole the compare script from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/125376/how-do-i-compare-binary-files-in-linux))

As you can see, in my case the binary remains patched even after quitting (`C3` is the opcode for the `ret` instruction. Instead of reopening the file with `oo+` as you did, I opened it in write mode with `w` and `A` (equivalent of `aaa`). I just tried myself and I ***couldn't*** patch binaries and save them (if anyone can give a more accurate explaination is welcome).

Answer (score 6):

This is normal and expected behaviour. when you are in the debugger what you are modifying is the process memory, not the disk file.

Comment: Being a new be in the huge world of reverse ingeniering, I had not this idea in my mind, the next time, I'll be ready for similar cases (before asking) ^^